# Rails data-remote attribute not always requesting a JS response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_for` with `remote: :true`, but the problem is that it seems to only be submitted remotely about half of the time. Sometimes I will get a `ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat)` error from the server, which is configured to only respond to `format.js`, and most of the time the form will work perfectly.

Is there some way I can call `$.rails` to make sure that the data-remote binding is taking effect? I have turbolinks turned off. Here is the code for the form:

```
= form_for [:admin, @seating_chart], remote: 'true', authenticity_token: true, multipart: true do |f|
    %br
    .form-group.text-center
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group.text-center
      = f.label :venue_id
      = f.collection_select :venue_id, Venue.all, :id, :name
    .form-group.text-center
      = f.label :chart_image
      = f.file_field :chart_image, id: :seating_chart_file
    .actions.text-center
      = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'
      \|
      = link_to 'Back', :back, class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

EDIT: upon further investigation it seems to only happen when I upload an image - if I don't upload the image then the error doesn't occur.

Comment: you can't use remote submission for file uploads. use a different solution for that like jquery fileupload.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to upload file with ajax request it can't be achieved directly.
The solution for this case is `remotipart`

[Remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)

And this is a demo of it

[Demo](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/12/rails-ajax-file-upload-using-remotipart.html)

Comment: ah i didn't ask the question.